# Is there any way to hide my code?

Tags: ruby, watir

I usually do a project and deploy it on the client machine, but all the Ruby/WATIR scripts are clearly visible to everyone. Is there any way to hide my code? Or is there any way I can secure my code? Or Is there any way to lock a folder through Ruby?

Comment: there are some ways, but nothing that cannot be circumvented with 5 minutes of effort.

Comment: It is worth noting that hiding your code does not make it more secure. See this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529822/should-i-disclose-database-ids-in-the-url/29532281#29532281

Comment: Three different requirements in your question.  Locking folders, hiding code, and security, are all very different questions.

Comment: I know all are very different question, but my motto was whether any of the way could help me to achieve what's required.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jRuby and create a JAR using [Warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler) but that will only stop non-geek users. [Here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/watir-webdriver-in-conjunction-with-java) a link about using watir in jRuby

Converting the script to an executable file like with [Ocra](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.be/2009/05/ocra-one-click-ruby-application-builder.html) is also an option.

Securing the script and let it run in another security context could work.

But what I would do is make it a web-app that can be run anywhere while nobody can see the source code. With a nice framework like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) that shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I don't remember well, but doesn't Ocra temporarily extract all necessary files to run the program? The source files become visible, if the user knows where to search.

Comment: yes I believe it does, I would put it in the same category as the first solution for non-geek users

Comment: @peter I need to run WATIR scripts as well, Do JRuby supports WATIR? If it supports, Can I do everything what I do using Ruby?

Comment: @RAJ, it should, i added a link to the response

Answer (score 0):

Code obfuscation is one option. You can use tools like [RubyScript2Exe](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/) or [AllInOneRuby](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/allinoneruby/index.html) to obfuscate your code or make them difficult to understand. However these tools have their own flaws which are nicely discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2123468/3035830).

Comment: AFAIK none of these are obfuscators.

Comment: true. But thats closest to Ruby obfuscation Ruby that I know of. I have also provided a link to other SO on same topic that might help OP point in right direction.